# How to make a generic R function inherit the class of its input?

Tags: r, class, inheritance, r-s3

Let the following code:

```r
x <- 1:5
class(x) <- "bar"

foo <- function(x) {
    UseMethod("foo")
}

foo.bar <- function(x) {
    y <- max(x)
    return(y)
}
```

I would like the output of `foo(x)` to have the same class as `x` (i.e., "bar"). The obvious way to do it is to add a `class(y) <- class(x)` inside `foo.bar()`, but I would like to know if/how I could do that in `foo()` itself.

The reason for this is that my real case has several generics, each one with 10+ methods, so if I could inherit the class in the generics, I'd just have to modify those instead of tens of methods.

Comment: "but I would like to know if I could do that in foo() itself" No, you can't. Think about what you are asking. Methods are free to return anything. How should the generic then enforce something regarding their return values?

Answer (score 4):

Rename `foo` to `foo_`, say, and then define `foo` to call `foo_` and then set the class.

```
foo_ <- foo
foo <- function(x) structure(foo_(x), class = class(x))
foo(x)
```

giving:

```
[1] 5
attr(,"class")
[1] "bar"
```